# Validation on input does not work properly

Tags: javascript

I have a validation function which I used other stackoverflow questions to write but this function is not working. The validation is done on an input field with javascript. It should only accept numbers (no zeros, signs, alphabets). Does any one have any suggestion?

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
        $(".myQuantityClass").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57 || e.which == 48)) {
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<tr>
<td class='quantity'><input type='text' class='myQuantityClass' value='1' another_id="+product_id+" onkeyup='addQuantity(this," + price + ");'></td></tr>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return when the key is correct..

```
<input type='text' class='myQuantityClass' value='1' onkeyup='addQuantity();'><br/>
<input type='text' class='myQuantityClass' value='1' onkeyup='addQuantity();'><br/>
<input type='text' class='myQuantityClass' value='1' onkeyup='addQuantity();'><br/>
<span id='total'></span>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function () {   
  $(".myQuantityClass").keypress(function (e) {
    var k = e.which;
    if ((k > 48 && k < (48+10)) || k == 8 || k == 0) return;
    return false;
  });
});
function addQuantity() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".myQuantityClass").each(function(idx,el){
        total += el.value|0;
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Kokizzu unfortunately your code is not validating!!

Comment: Kokizzu it is still not validating anything! Any suggestion?

Comment: it works in my PC '___') are you sure no error on your `JavaScript` console?

Comment: Yes! Because the same validation is working on another field!

Comment: please edit your question, providing the html tags that uses `myQuantityClass` class, maybe the problem not in the javascript but on the markup/html

Comment: I have added the html code to the question. Thank you.

Comment: could you provide the code for addQuantity function

Answer (score 1):

demo here --> http://jsfiddle.net/ebzsdk88/1/

```
$(".myQuantityClass").keypress(function (e) {
     return (e.which>48 && e.which<58);
});
```

Comment: Just do `return (e.which>48 && e.which<58);` It makes little sense to do if bool return bool else return bool.

Comment: Vladu unfortunately it does not validate anything and it allows all characters.

Comment: see my demo , i think you have some issues in your code

Comment: @Jonast92 Yes I checked the demo, it is working fine. I Have added my html code in case there is something wrong with that!